# ORA-06502 "number precision too large" only in PL/SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle12c, plsqldeveloper, ora-06502

There is a package with type.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_TYPES IS
PRAGMA SERIALLY_REUSABLE;
  SUBTYPE my_number IS NUMBER(3,0);
END MY_TYPES;
/
```

There is a procedure:

```
DECLARE
  PROCEDURE print(my_number_i IN my_types.my_number) IS
  BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line(my_number_i);
  END;
BEGIN
  print(my_number_i => 35);
END;
/
```

The problem is that such a call gives an error in PL/SQL Developer.

> ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large.

But if you substitute the value `my_number_i => !=35`, the procedure is completed.

However, if you run it from SQL Developer, everything works. If you run it via SQL*Plus, it also works. It only does not work from PL/SQL Developer.

Please tell me what the problem might be?

Comment: "CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TYPES ", not "package"

Comment: your "create or replace" does not work. Please post the correct code.

Comment: I can't change an existing package

Comment: The point is that `subtype my_number number(3,0);` is invalid; presumably this isn't your real code and you've partially changed the names, but not correctly. You probably didn't mean to have the `subtype` in there? Or you meant `subtype my_number is number(3,0);` ? Please show minimal *working* code - at least working to the point you get the error you refer to. With `is` and a missing semicolon added your code doesn't error at all... [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=0688cbf43c58aa1715f96bc5bc0106b0)

Comment: The question is detailed

Comment: OK, thanks; that is strange. It might be worth including the full version of PL/SQL Developer you're seeing this in. If it's very old then maybe it's a version clash with 12c. (I don't have any version installed so I can't help...)

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your `CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE MY_TYPES..`  ..But are you sure about your `declare procedure print(my_number_i in my_types.my_number);`? That's it's not `CREATE OR REPLACE procedure print(my_number_i in my_types.my_number) IS`?

Comment: @Scratte - it's a procedure that's local to the anonymous block. That's valid, and works. (Except, it seems, in PL/SQL Developer...)

Comment: It works fine for me in PL/SQL Developer 13 and 14 (Oracle 19.3) after correcting the semicolon in `procedure print`, which should be `is`.

Comment: Can confirm PL/SQL Developer 14, it worked in SQL Window, Test Window and also Command Window and Oracle 11.2.0.4, the `;` instead of `IS` was added by @AlexPoole most likely by mistake, I proposed an edit that is waiting for approval.

Comment: @KayaNatsumi - hmm, not sure how/why I added a semicolon instead of `IS` - I did it right in my fiddle; or why my comment mentions a missing semicolon as well as `IS`. Must have been an off day... I asked the OP to include their PL/SQL Developer version but that doesn't seem to have happened. If it it's really doing this then I imagine it's a bug in an older version.